# Extract Date as Number or as Datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi, powerquery

We have a data warehouse with tables and views from our ERP-System. The views contain the same information as the tables but the date has a different type.
The views have a date like '01.01.2020'
The tables have a date like a number '19001'.

Now, from a performance/ refresh point of view. What is more performant? Should I use the original table with the date as a number?
We are talking about 10mio rows.

Comment: What does "19001" mean?

Comment: It means 2019 and the first day of the year > 01.01.2019

Comment: It is probably better to store dates using the correct datatype in the database.   I would be inclined to convert them when the data is ingested.

Comment: Thanks! And what takes longer with a Select *? Is there a significant difference by refreshing 5mio rows with a number column compared to a date column?

Comment: You haven't really explained what you are doing and what performance you are trying to compare. Performance and refresh of what? Querying the view has to do the conversion from number to date; but if you need the actual date then that has to happen somewhere, so are you asking if it's quicker to query the number and convert in... whatever app/layer is running the query? Are you applying a date filter as part of a query?Or are you talking about updating the table/view? Updating the view would need an instead-of trigger, which would slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion on the fly of your numeric is easy enough to do

```
SQL> select to_date('19041','YYDDD') from dual;

TO_DATE('
---------
10-FEB-19
```

but rest assured that storing dates as anything but dates is generally going to get you into trouble down the track. If you can convert it on load, or even use a virtual column and then gather optimizer stats on that column, you'll be better off then using the number column directly.

Here's some video demonstrations of where things generally go bad once you start drifting away from the "natural" data type for data.

https://youtu.be/cqnuwNc4-1M